# A Question About Probability of ratio of $\max(\cdot)$?

Tags: definite-integrals, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, order-statistics

In My field , I reached to this problem.

**Assumptions**:

Consider $x_i,\hat{x}_i$ are iid (identical and independent) samples of a joint distribution (e.g., exponential). And also, assume we have $N$ such pairs.

Now the question is :

$$P=P_r\left(\frac{\max(x_i)}{\max(\hat{x}_i)}>K\right)$$

---

**My Answer:**

I started with induce concomitant theorem (concomitant order static) as below:
I am ordering in ascending: $x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_N$

Therefore, we ave:
$$ P=1-\Pr(\max(x_i)<K\max(\hat{x}_i))$$
$$ \Pr(\max(x_i)<\max(\hat{x}_i))=P_r(x_1<\hat{x}_N K, x_2<\hat{x}_N K,\ldots,x_N<\hat{x}_N K)$$

but, it seems to be very complex integration! (exhaustive one). i mean,  we must let $x_n=t$ which is translating to $N-1$ integrals based on $t$. Ultimately, we must integrate the resulted expression with respect to $x_n$. I will be happy to have your comments, hints or suggestion.